# AWS CloudFormation reusing the existing resource when creating or deploying new template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am developing my CloudFormation template. I have an S3 bucket resource in my template with the following code.

```
StorageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: pathein-directory-storage
      AccessControl: PublicRead
```

As you can see I set the DeletionPolicy to Retain because I want to retain the Bucket and its data when the template is deleted. At some point, I explicitly deleted the template. But my S3 bucket was not deleted.

Now, I am trying to deploy my template again. But the deployment is failing because the bucket already exists with the same name. How can I figure my template to use the existing bucket if there is already one?

Comment: Hi Wai. In the interests of writing clear questions, you may wish to spend some time learning the difference between "cause" (an effect between two related things) and "because" (the reason for something). Native English speakers often colloquially shorten "because" to "cos", but it is still wrong, and is inappropriate for technical writing. Clarity is important on Stack Overflow (not least because expecting all readers to be fluent in colloquial English is not fair on them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I figure my template to use the existing bucket if there is already one?

You have to [import it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) into CFN as shown in:

- [Importing existing resources into a stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html)

Luckily, `AWS::S3::Bucket` is one of the resources that are [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) for the import operation.

You begin the procedure in the console when you `Create stack with existing resources`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Margin. What about the RDS resource? Does it support RDS?

Comment: Thanks Marcin, this is the solution.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Hi. No problem. Yes, RDS is also supported.